# how to know how many if condition is true in your code c++

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have written code with `if` conditions and every time the user gets an answer right he gets +1 and at the end I wanted to show him his final score but I don't know how to know how many `if` conditions are true.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using  namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num[4][4] 
    {
        {2,5,26,677} ,
        {2,3,7,5041} ,
        {1,2,3,4},
        {1,3,5,7} };
    
     int ans[4];
    
     cout << "hello user.\n"  ;
     cout << "write your answer"<<endl;
     cout << "2, 5, 26 , ";
     cin >> ans[0];
     cout << "write your answer\n";
     cout << "2, 3, 7,  ";
     cin >> ans[1];
     cout << "write your answer\n";
     cout << "1, 2, 3, ";
     cin >> ans[2];
     cout << "hello user.\n";
     cout << "write your answer" << endl;
     cout << "1, 3, 5,";
     cin >> ans[3];
     if (ans[0] == 677) {
         cout << "your second answer is right \n";
     }
     else {
         cout << "your second answer is wrong, the right answer is 5041\n";
     }
     if (ans[1] == 5041) {
         cout << "your second answer is right \n";
     }
     else {
         cout << "your second answer is wrong, the right answer is 5041\n";
     }
     if (ans[2] == 4) {
         cout << "your third answer is right \n";
     }
     else {
         cout << "your third answer is wrong, the right answer is 4 \n";
     }
     cout << "your score  is ";
     if (ans[3] == 7) {
         cout << "your fourth answer is right \n";
     }
     else {
         cout << "your fourth answer is wrong, the right answer is 7 \n";
     }
 }
```

Comment: increment a counter inside each statement? Or better rewrite your code into a for loop rather than repeating the same code 4 times

Comment: I would also tell the user what's expected to be done with the numbers in order to produce the correct answer.

Comment: Your code should not repeat itself and actually make use of the data inside `num`

Comment: From the User: `cout << "program, what is the question?\n"`  You are asking the User for answers, but not supplying a question.  Is this Jeopardy game?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how often something happens you can introduce a counter and incremented it accordingly. For example, the following code counts odd numbers in the interval `[a,b)` and prints the result:

```
 int a = 0;
 int b = 42;
 int counter = 0;
 for (int i=a; i<b; ++i) {
      if ( i%2 ) ++counter;
 }

 std::cout << "value of counter after the loop: " << counter;
```

Comment: `const int odd_counter = (b - a) / 2 + a % 2;` ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 `const int odd_counter = (b - a >> 1) + (a & 1);` ;-)